# AndroidStudio 4.1 - Why Database Inspector slow down my Android emulator?

Tags: android-studio, database-inspector

I have recently updated Android Studio to version 4.1, since this version it's possible to watch the app database.

When I use this functionality, my Android emulator is very slow. The same scenario appear when I'm using a physical phone.

Slowest activities are those which get data from database with the Room library.

It is impossible to switch off "Database Inspector", I have to invalidate my cache and restart Android Studio.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: My database queries works too slow as well when Database Inspector is used... Please update if you found a solution.

Comment: I faced the same problem. 
If anyone know how to bypass this, pls post a solution.
The most weird thing is you can not turn off this feature, and you build run slow everytime you debug!!!

Comment: I did not specify, but my problem occurs on Windows 10, I could not test on other systems. Is it the same for you?

Comment: It happens to me with a real device, as well as with an emulator. Also interesting when you run you app in debug the database inspector does not show up. I was trying to debug for several hours why my app got slowed down, my thoughts where dead locks in db. But the speed fixed itself after I unplugged the phone from the ADB, a relief and a pity in the same time :D.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues. When the App inspector is running, my database queries run up to few seconds.You can turn off inspection in App Inspection window - click on a process name in the top left corner and choose "Stop Inspectors".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Invalidate Caches and restart. This will start the Android Studio again without loading the Database inpsector

Answer (score -1):

It's been a long time since I've worked on my project in native Android. In Android Studio version 4.2.2, it is now possible to stop the Database Inspector.
This solves the problem perfectly ;)

[image: How to stop database inspector]

Answer (score -3):

if you are using kotlin Use **Coroutine** to handle Database operation or if you are using java use thread to handle database operation.

if you want to learn more about coroutine go to youtube ,here available lot more information.

Comment: This is not the topic of the discussion. I have any problems to use the database with room, and I handle peferctly my database operations ;).